# Not able to install Python 3.9.5 on Linux Mint 19

Tags: python

hope someone could help here. I already checked a lot of instructions around the web and did not work. I just would like to install through the terminal the latest Python version 3.9.5 (I have on my distro the version 2.7). Thanks. This is the output I get more often:

`$ sudo apt-get install python3`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3 is already the newest version (3.6.7-1~18.04).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libllvm9 libreoffice-style-galaxy linux-headers-5.3.0-45
  linux-headers-5.3.0-45-generic linux-image-5.3.0-45-generic
  linux-modules-5.3.0-45-generic linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-45-generic
  Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = "en_GB",
LC_ALL = (unset),
LC_TIME = "it_IT.UTF-8",
LC_MONETARY = "it_IT.UTF-8",
LC_ADDRESS = "it_IT.UTF-8",
LC_TELEPHONE = "it_IT.UTF-8",
LC_NAME = "it_IT.UTF-8",
LC_MEASUREMENT = "it_IT.UTF-8",
LC_IDENTIFICATION = "it_IT.UTF-8",
LC_NUMERIC = "it_IT.UTF-8",
LC_PAPER = "it_IT.UTF-8",
LANG = "en_GB"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Setting up ubuntu-advantage-tools (27.0.2~18.04.1) ...
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
    locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uaclient'
   dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-advantage-tools (--configure):
 installed ubuntu-advantage-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error        exit status 1
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-minimal:
  ubuntu-minimal depends on ubuntu-advantage-tools; however:
  Package ubuntu-advantage-tools is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ubuntu-advantage-tools
 ubuntu-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Have you read `python3 is already the newest version`. Python 3.6.5 is the newest version in your repositories. The error message comes from package `ubuntu-minimal` not from `python3`.

Answer (score 1):

First thing update your Python Path with this:

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${HOME}:/usr/bin/python:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

And also looks like your package database is corrupted. Try running this:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

And as far as python goes, python 3.6.7 is already installed on your system.
Running `python --version` will list out python 2.7 which usually comes pre-installed with most Debian/Ubuntu based distros. Instead run `python3 --version`. This will give you python 3.6.7.

If you need the latest version of Python, you can do so with the **deadsnakes** ppa.